# How to check if a checkbox is checked in a qtablewidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'm setting a filtering tool in Python 3.7 and I'm using pyqt5. I've created a qtablewidget to store the filters and their complementaries chosen by the user. I'd like to allow the user to combine filters over a data so I added grouped checkboxes  in each row to select wanted filters.

Which commands should I use to loop over my qtable to get which checkbox is selected please?

[image]

```py
def bindApply(self):
    checked_list = []
    for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
        #print(self.tableWidget.rowCount())
        if self.tableWidget.item(i, 1).checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            checked_list.append([i,1])
        elif self.tableWidget.item(i, 2).checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            checked_list.append([i,2])
        else:
            pass
    return(checked_list)
```

I expect a list containing the indexes of selected rows and columns but my function returns nothing.

Here is a reproducible example:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(550, 350)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(550, 350))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(550, 350))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 500, 200))
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(0)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        self.pushButton_Save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_Save.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 250, 100, 50))
        self.pushButton_Save.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.pushButton_Save.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.pushButton_Save.setObjectName("pushButton_Save")
        self.pushButton_Apply = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_Apply.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 250, 100, 50))
        self.pushButton_Apply.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.pushButton_Apply.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 50))
        self.pushButton_Apply.setObjectName("pushButton_Apply")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 550, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Name"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Filter"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "complementary"))
        self.pushButton_Save.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save"))
        self.pushButton_Apply.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Apply"))
        #============================  BINDING  ===============================
        self.pushButton_Save.clicked.connect(self.bindSave)
        self.pushButton_Apply.clicked.connect(self.bindApply)
        
    def bindSave(self):
        numRows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        self.tableWidget.insertRow(numRows)
        
        groupButton = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(self.tableWidget)
        groupButton.setExclusive(True)
        it1 = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("filter "+str(numRows))
        self.tableWidget.setItem(numRows, 0, it1)
        ch_bx1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        groupButton.addButton(ch_bx1)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(numRows, 1, ch_bx1)
        ch_bx2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox()
        groupButton.addButton(ch_bx2)
        self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(numRows, 2, ch_bx2)
        
    def bindApply(self):
        checked_list = []
        for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
            #print(self.tableWidget.rowCount())
            if self.tableWidget.item(i, 1).checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                checked_list.append([i,1])
            elif self.tableWidget.item(i, 2).checkState() == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
                checked_list.append([i,2])
            else:
                pass
        print(checked_list)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui        = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the state of the check boxes assigned to the cells, not the state of the item associated with the cell, i.e.

```
def bindApply(self):
    checked_list = []
    for i in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount()):
        #print(self.tableWidget.rowCount())
        if self.tableWidget.cellWidget(i, 1).isChecked():
            checked_list.append([i,1])
        elif self.tableWidget.cellWidget(i, 2).isChecked():
            checked_list.append([i,2])
        else:
            pass
    print(checked_list)
```